# Conditionally hiding a segment of json in javascript code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ionic-framework

I want to hide the destructiveText property conditionally, is that possible? So, say there is a variable called `showDelete`. I want to show destructiveText to show only when `showDelete = true`. Is it possible to conditionally exclude it from the json?

```
  $ionicActionSheet.show({
      buttons: [
        { text: 'Share' },
        { text: 'Report'},
      ],
      destructiveText: 'Delete', //I want to hide this delete element when showDelete is false
      titleText: 'Actions',
      cancelText: 'Cancel',
      cancel: function() {
            // add cancel code..
      },
      ...
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Define your config object outside of the function call, then you can modify  properties using conditionals as well as use methods like `angular.extend()`

```
var opts = {
      buttons: [
        { text: 'Share' },
        { text: 'Report'},
      ],

      titleText: 'Actions',
      cancelText: 'Cancel',
      cancel: function() {
            // add cancel code..
      }
} 

if(showDelete){
   opts.destructiveText = 'Delete';
}

 $ionicActionSheet.show(opts);
```

Comment: how I  can get buttonClicked event of the buttons such as 'Share' and 'Reports'